# ¿Es posible montar dos ImageIcon en un JOptionPane?

Tags: java, java-swing

Quisiera que aparezcan dos imágenes en un solo `JOptionPane` ya sea de entrada o mensaje.

```
Object seleccion = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Seleccion Respuesta Correcta",
                          "Preguntas",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                          new ImageIcon("imagenes/img1.png"),
                          new Object[] { "opcion 1", "opcion 2" }, 
                       "");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede usar el constructor de tipo `(Componente,Objeto,String,int)` donde el componente será la ventana padre *(para el ejemplo solo null)* , el parámetro Objeto será un `Array` de `JLabel` donde estarán las imágenes , El tercero será el Titulo  del dialogo y el `int` hace referencia al tipo de mensaje mediante un `icono`.

```
JLabel[] arr = {
      new JLabel("",new ImageIcon("rutaimagen1"),JLabel.LEFT),
      new JLabel("",new ImageIcon("rutaimagen2"),JLabel.RIGHT)
      };
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,arr,"Mensaje!!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
String valor = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, arr, "Ingrese Valor",
                                           JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
System.out.println(valor);
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, me ha servido mucho tu aporte, saludos Master.